# Hide menu item in WP with .php?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating a website for a client and I'm using TranslatePress for WP to make it multilingual. Therefore, it's a premium add-on for TranslatePress to hide menu items for specific languages, I would like to do this on my own, seems pretty unuseful to buy a 100$ plugin just for one add-on.

I tried to edit functions.php file with something like this -

```
    <?php 

$current_language = get_locale();

if( $current_language == 'lv' ){
.menu-item-661 {
    display: none;
}
}


?>
```

But that completely doesn't work. I have no clue what would be the right approach here, but I tried to hide a class, in this case, .menu-item-661 to display none.

Can someone please give me an advice?

Thanks

Comment: Of course that can’t work, you can not mix CSS directly into PHP like that. And even if you figured out the right syntax PHP-wise here, CSS output as plain text still doesn’t do anything - it would have to be content of a `<style>` element to begin with.

Comment: I would probably handle this without any custom programming, but via the stylesheet and a little bit of configuration. WP puts the language into the `lang` attribute of the `html` element - so you can easily use that to create rules in your stylesheet, that hide other elements based on this. `html[lang="en-US"] .hide-me-when-en-us { display: none !important; }` - and then all you have to do, is give your menu items you don’t want to see when the language is en-US, the class `hide-me-when-en-us`.

Comment: Thank You, Sir, for giving me a hint. 

Since I won't add any more new menu items and this is the only one, i solved my problem with a simple -  `:lang(lv) .menu-item-661 {
    display: none;
}`